# How to calculate accurate yaw using Magnetometer and Accelerometer

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, gyroscopes

I'm currently using mobile device accelerometer+gyro+magnetometer attitude to get roll, pitch, and yaw. However, yaw is drifting and becoming not accurate over time.

I read there is a way to calculate the yaw using a combination of accelerometer and magnetometer that will keep yaw accurate with a compensation for the constant drift, however, I haven't yet found a working formula.

**UPDATE**

I could compensate the yaw drift by using the following formula:

Create initial reference point (fixed world frame reference) using magnetometer:

```
m_w = (m_x,m_y,m_z)
```

Take current magnetomer point (also fixed world frame reference) using magnetometer:

```
n_w = (n_x,n_y,n_z)
```

Convert projected reading to angles

```
a = atan2(m_z,m_x)
b = atan2(n_z,n_x)
```

Yaw drift can be calculated as follows

```
y_d = (a-b) * 180 / PI
```

Now deduct result from current accelerometer yaw.

Comment: FYI, _walla_ is spelled, "[voilà](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/voila?s=t)".

Comment: (I edited out the superfluous and offending "WALLA," but upvoted the above comment since it is an important warning regarding the inane misspelling of "voila.")

Answer (score 0):

On Earth, you can assume that the geomagnetic field is locally uniform and constant, pointing to South, and horizontal. Happily, a magnetometer can be used to measure this magnetic field: knowing its direction on the magnetometer frame of reference, you can derive the orientation of the magnetometer, ie. you can find yaw.

Comment: Great, I know that :) I'm looking for "how to" do that calculation using the magnetometer. A formula would be great.

Comment: In the US and Europe, where most of our readers are, you should *not* assume that the magnetic field is horizontal; the dip angle is typically about 70°, with some variation as you move around. See e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dip